# Are there cons of my technique for designing multilingual websites

Tags: php, css, web, multilingual

I am designing a multilingual website and it supports both `ltr` and `rtl`.

1. Language:

   I stored languages in arrays like this `$lan=array('browse'=>'تصفح','add'=>'إضافة','signin'=>'تسجيل دخول');` and saved them in separate php files and I `include` the selected language. I use it within the HTML codes like `<?php echo $lan['browse'];?>`
2. direction:

   Most of direction issues can be solved by the CSS property `dir`. However, sometimes you need to specify different properties for different directions. Therefore, I gave the body a class name which is either "rtl" or "ltr" and then I use it as the following:

   ```
   .brs_search_box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 199px;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        height: 500px;
   }
   .rtl .brs_search_box{
        border-left: 0;
   }
   .ltr .brs_search_box{
        border-right: 0;
   }
   ```

Are there cons for this technique? for example would the large size array have a bad effect?

Comment: you could take a look at this website from zend, they explain a lot of methods http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.adapter.html

Comment: You may want to use selectors in CSS, like `.brs_search_box[dir="ltr"] { something }` along with `.brs_search_box[dir="rtl"] { something else }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issues you may find is if you haven't explicitly translated EVERY part of the text that you are echoing.

For example you may `echo $lan['this is some text'];` but what if you haven't translated this text yet? This would display on screen as blank if you haven't set up some sort of fallback for default text to use.

One of the best sytems for PHP multi-lingual sites I've used is `gettext` and you can check it out in the PHP manual on the following link:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

I admit when I first started using it that it wasn't so intuitive to set up and you need a couple of extra tools to get it going but once you have learnt it and set it up it works very well in my opinion and you would also have a new string to your bow for future production.

You basically wrap all your text in the function `__()`, for example `__('This is some text')` and it then searches your translation files and displays the relevant text.

This seperates everything out into seperate files which you can then use to easily translate text. This is also useful for handing to translation companies/friends/next door neighbours cats to translate without them touching any of your actual application files.

In addition, if it doesn't find a translated string for your specified text then it will just output it as provided inside the `__()` function.

It makes it very scalable for adding new languages over time.

I think there are other options available too for you to look at and yours would work, but for an industry accepted, scalable approach it might be good to look at `gettext`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is a proper *toolchain* for dealing with translations. Do your arrays support plurals? Context? Domains? Categories? Comments? Most important of all: do they support *automated extraction*?

If you're just manually adding each new string to an array, you have a mountain of work for every single new string you add. It's important for a translation system to support fully automatic extraction of strings. You just mark your strings in your source code, run a script and automatically get files with translatable strings out. Every time you run it, the files are updated and merged with the latest changes from your source code. Without this, the process becomes unmanageable very quickly.

Further, since you will probably have to work with external, non-technical translators at some point in the future, having strings in a format which is well supported by a variety of tools is important.

As @Peter points out, gettext and similar established tools have all that. Your arrays don't.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using a language array is good. However from experience, I would suggest 2 techniques:

A language config file. So you would have say en_gb.php and arabaic.php and each would contain an array of translations. These files can then be preloaded depending on the users language preferences or IP addresses, this technique is pretty limitless as the translations are kept in one central location, and you can add as many languages as you like, i.e. french.php

A database. You can design this how you want, but ideally you will have a table with a column for template-words and a column for each translation. As this table isnt likely to change often, you can use disk based or memory based cacheing for speed.

With either of the above techniques, you just use a templating system and plug in the respective translation on page load. However from experience I would suggest, testing the site in both languages thoroughly, as it isnt possible for languages to be translated word for word. What takes 200px to display in one language might take 400px in another. So the site will have to be designed with that in mind.